# Putting data from database into variable using PHP (PDO, MVC)

Tags: php, mysql, model-view-controller, pdo

Today I have looked all over the internet for a good answer. I almost got the answer from this site but that solution didn't work.

Here is what I need to do:

In the database there is a token stored that is going to be used for qr codes. I have already made something to generate the qr code when hardcoded:

```
                $token_qr = "a86ad6352e939eea67da45b8731c3a8d62dcas1r";
                $url_qr = some url;

                $qr_code = array(
                    "token" => $token_qr, 
                    "url" => $url_qr
                ); // end array
                $qr_code_encoded = json_encode($qr_code, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
                $smarty->assign('qr_code_encoded', base64_encode($qr_code_encoded));
```

The base64 string is put in a url so the qr image can be generated.

Now I need to make it dynamically, the url is always the same but the token is always different. In the model where all the database statements are present I made this:

```
     Class Webservices {
        public function GetToken($token) {
        $pdo = Database::Get();

        $query = "SELECT `site__webservice`.* FROM `site__webservice` WHERE `token` = :token"; // SQL select statement
        $params = array(":token" => $token); // bind params
        $result = $pdo->Select($query, $params); // run query

        // fetch token
        if($result) {
            $row = PDO::FETCH_ASSOC($result);

            return $row[$token];                
        } else {
            return false;
        }
      }
    }
```

With this function I try to get the token from the database and store this in the $token_qr variable which stand in the controller. To call this I use this:

```
   $webservices = new Webservices();

   $token_qr = $webservices->GetToken($token);
```

The output of this function is now always false. Is there something wrong with my statement or is it in the loop that I created?

Maybe it is something really easy but I can't see the problem and find a solution for it. Thanks in advance for the response!

Comment: ` return $row[$token]` why `$token` ? i think should be only `return $row`

Comment: what framework are you using ?

Comment: @chris85 `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC($result);` doesn't make sense.

Comment: Yea, just looked at that again. `token` usage is incorrect as well, `$row[$token]` is going to be `$row['valuequeryed']` where as it should be `$row['token']`.

Comment: I have changed some things in my codes. It now looks like this: $row = $result->fetchAll(FETCH_ASSOC);
    
    return $row['token']; but it is still returning false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need fetch the result before return, use `fetch()` or `fetchAll()`. Seems `Select()` works likes pdo `execute()` so it's return PDOStatment, fetch it to get the results.

```
if($result) {
   $row = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   return $row;
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reaction. I have tried it but the loop still return false...

Comment: @B.Goossen, in `select()` method, check if `execute()` return an error, add `or die(print_r($statement->errorInfo()));`